# Getting the cycle time of items in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got a table of data which have log the history of some items. The items evolves over time and are passing different states like "Submitted", "In Verification", "Completed":

| ID | Modified Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01.01.2021 12:01 | Submitted |
| 123 | 02.01.2021 12:02 | In Verification |
| 123 | 03.01.2021 12:03 | Completed |
| 345 | 06.01.2021 12:04 | Submitted |
| 345 | 04.01.2021 12:05 | In Verification |
| 345 | 19.01.2021 18:06 | Completed |

I want to know how many days each item was in a specific state. Is there a way to do this with PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the analytical function `LEAD()`. In your question is not clear that the statuses follow a specific workflow or they are meaningless, so the query below is generic.

You can do:

```
select *,
  lead(modified_date) over(partition by id order by modified_date) 
  - modified_date as diff
from t
```

Result:

```
id   modified_date             status           diff                               
---- ------------------------- ---------------- ---------------------------------- 
123  2021-01-01T12:01:00.000Z  SUBMITTED        {"days":1,"minutes":1}             
123  2021-01-02T12:02:00.000Z  IN_VERIFICATION  {"days":1,"minutes":1}             
123  2021-01-03T12:03:00.000Z  COMPLETED        null                               
345  2021-01-04T12:05:00.000Z  IN_VERIFICATION  {"days":1,"hours":23,"minutes":59} 
345  2021-01-06T12:04:00.000Z  SUBMITTED        {"days":13,"minutes":2}            
345  2021-01-19T12:06:00.000Z  COMPLETED        null
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kK9MheYXiTeN7Kidudz6ot/1).

Comment: Nice solution. I see it working in the DB fiddle but struggling to get it working in my real database. The code is accepted but it always returns NULL for diff.

Comment: @RangaB. Maybe we can help if  you can demo a simplified version of your special case in a fiddle.

Comment: Thank you. The error was on my side because I had the wrong data in my database. I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Window functions to get Access to the Following row and calculate the difference between the 2 Fields.
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-lead-function/

Without testing, it should look like something like that:

```
select *, 
Datediff(dd,[Modified Date],lead([Modified Date],1,GETDATE()) 
over 
(order by ID, [Modified Date])) as [Days between]
from log 
order by ID, [Modified Date]
```

With that you get the next Value from your table in your actual row and you can calculate with it. For Default Value actuall Date is used, but you can use every other Date you want.